# How to select Object below another Objects bounding box

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

I'm working on a Tumult Hype (Javascript) project to select items that share overlapping space (if their Bounding Boxes are taken into consideration).

For instance, the Orange Triangle's bounding box is represented by the Red Outline. Is there any way/logic that would enable selecting the  Green Triangle when it is below the Orange Triangle?

My original idea was to use the Path in an SVG based on it's ID. This works perfectly to select an unusual shaped Object and ignore it's bounding box. But, the Bounding Box still disallows selecting the lower level DOM Object.

[image: Bounding Box]

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to NOT use separate Objects (SVGs). Create 1 SVG that has all the Objects with unique paths that can be selected using their ID.